# Replace list value 'None' with zero in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]
```

I need to replace all `None` values with `0` and replace any value that is not `None` to `None`. So above list will become:

```
modified_a_list = [['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 0]]
```

I have code like this:

```
a_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]
b_list = a_list
modified_a_list = []
for item in b_list:
    if item[1]==None:
        item[1]=0
        modified_a_list.append(item)
    else:
        item[1] = 0
        modified_a_list.append(item)
print a_list, modified_a_list
```

My output becomes:

```
a_list = [['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 0]]
modified_a_list = [['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 0]]
```

`modified_a_list` looks OK. But why `a_list` is changed as well?

Comment: `a_list` and `b_list` are the same list. That's what `b_list = a_list` does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with list mutability.  When you do `b_list = a_list` you're just copying a reference to a_list, so changes to b_list will happen in a_list too.  Then the loop modifies the lists inside b_list.

Because there are nested lists, you can't just copy a_list with the slicing trick or anything like that.  Easiest is just to use deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
a_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]
b_list = deepcopy(a_list)
modified_a_list = []
for item in b_list:
    if item[1]==None:
        item[1]=0
        modified_a_list.append(item)
    else:
        item[1] = None
        modified_a_list.append(item)
print(a_list, modified_a_list)
```

Alternatively, you can just cut out the middleman and do a shallow copy of the inner lists inside the loop, i.e.:

```
a_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]
modified_a_list = []
for item in a_list:
    temp=item[:]
    if item[1]==None:
        temp[1]=0
        modified_a_list.append(temp)
    else:
        temp[1] = None
        modified_a_list.append(temp)
print(a_list, modified_a_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, when creating `b_list` it is basically a pointer to `a_list`. So when you work on `b_list` you are also working on `a_list`. If you want to leave `a_list` alone, you have to create a whole new list.

```
>>> a_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]
>>> 
>>> modified_a_list = [[a[0], 0 if a[1] is None else None] for a in a_list]
>>> 
>>> a_list
[['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]
>>> 
>>> modified_a_list
[['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, `item` is a *reference* to an element of `b_list`, which refers to the `a_list` as well. So when you do `item[1] = 0` in `b_list`, it sets the second element of `item` to 0, which is reflected in both references of the list.

```
    a_list \
            \
             ----> [ element1, element2, element3 ]
            /           |          |         |
    b_list /            |          |         |
                    ['a', 0]    ['b', 0]  ['c', None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 4], ['c', None]]

new_list = [[None if isinstance(b, int) else 0 if b == None else b for b in i] for i in a_list]
```

Output:

```
[['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 0]]
```

Comment: @vishes_shell - actually it isn't, it's just inefficient as you don't need to check for instance, nor you need to loop through the whole second list.

Comment: @zwer are you kiddin me? Nested list comprehension is alright, but 2 if-else clauses in single list comprehension? Whot?

Comment: @vishes_shell seems pretty straight-forward to read to me... it's needlessly loopy and inefficient, but it's not something that is unreadable. I've seen far worse offenders.

Comment: This is at least one solution, as it outputs the proper results.